# Running migration addConstraint Foreign Key not on Primary Key fields causes SQLite Error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to configure a Foreign Key association between two tables on 'non-PrimaryKey' fields for one-to-many relation:

```
Asset.belongsTo(AssetClass)
AssetClass.hasMany(Asset)
```

I create tables first and add the constraint in the third migration:

**migrations\20220621223626-create-asset.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Assets', {
      ticker: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      shortName: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      fullName: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      assetClass: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Assets');
  }
};
```

**migrations\20220622035610-create-asset-class.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('AssetClasses', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      prio: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('AssetClasses');
  }
};
```

**migrations\20220627211055-add-constraint-fk_asset-assetClass.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.addConstraint('Assets', {
      fields: ['assetClass'], //existing field in Assets table
      type: 'foreign key',
      name: 'fk_asset-assetClass',
      references: {
        table: 'AssetClasses', //reference to AssetClasses table
        field: 'name' //name of the target field
      }
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint('Assets', 'fk_asset-assetClass');
  }
};
```

After running `db::migrate` I am getting a following error message:

```
SQLITE_ERROR: foreign key mismatch - "Assets_backup" referencing "AssetClasses"
```

which leaves me with a `Assets_backup` table in the database which I need to remove manually.

**What seems to works though is:**

Creating a new column `assetClassId` in Assets table and referencing it to Primary Key field (`id`) of AssetClasses table:

```
//addConstraint migration
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.addConstraint('Assets', {
      fields: ['assetClassId'], //existing field in Assets table
      type: 'foreign key',
      name: 'fk_asset-assetClass',
      references: {
        table: 'AssetClasses', //reference to AssetClasses table
        field: 'id' //name of the target field
      }
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint('Assets', 'fk_asset-assetClass');
  }
};

//createTable Assets migration
assetClassId: {
  allowNull: false,
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER
},
```

How can I make it work for existing non-PK fields?

Comment: At least `name` field should have a unique index to be able to be referenced in a foreign key. And I'm not sure if Sqlite supports this

Comment: You are right! It is actually written in the Sequelize documentation as well: 
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#creating-associations-referencing-a-field-which-is-not-the-primary-key